# Getting library dependencies for DirectX sample applications

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

I am reading a book on directx and wish to run the books sample applications. The instructions to do this are found here: https://bitbucket.org/pvarcholik/real-time-3d-rendering-with-directx-and-hlsl/src/master/
I am unsure as to what to do for the 'Library Dependencies' sections. Any help?

Comment: You need to download them, and point your compiler to where the headers/lib files are (assuming you used prebuilt binaries). Exactly how this is done depends on your development environment, which you havent specified (for example in Visual Studio you would need to go and add paths to additional include directories / additional library directories, and then specify which libraries you depend on)

Comment: I'd start by downloading and installing (which probably consists of configuring and compiling some of them) the listed libraries. Follow their installation instructions and you should be good to go. If not, that's a good time to ask a Stack Overflow question. What you have right now is too wide open to write a decent answer for.

Comment: I have no idea how to proceed in order the get the samples to work. I thought that someone could look at the steps and be able to give clear, simple instructions on how to get everything done so that I can run the sample applications.

Comment: @Borgleader please refer to my previous comment. Would appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 2):

Per the notes, these projects use vcpkg now for the dependencies, specifically the ports for [directxtk](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/directxtk), [ms-gsl](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/ms-gsl), [assimp](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/assimp), and [imgui](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/imgui). The NuGet package manager is still used for the C++/WinRT headers--I've got a personal project to create a vcpkg port for that as well.

The **Quick Start (latest)** instructions tell you how to clone and install each of these vcpkg packages. This will build those libraries and place them in a central location for the samples to consume them. The `vcpkg integrate install` instruction makes them available to Visual Studio.

> For more on the vcpkg C++ Package Manager, see [vcpkg.io](https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/README.html) and [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-a-tool-to-acquire-and-build-c-open-source-libraries-on-windows/)